# Reporting improper use of "F" button on websites

Tags: facebook-like

I know that third party websites are not allowed to change, modify, or hide the "Like" button.

However, is it allowed to change, modify, or hide the "F" button (the square blue button with "f" in it)?  And if it is not allowed then how can I report it?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Ask Facebook, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I will, if I can find WHERE. Facebook has become very big and complicated with little chance finding relative info.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot change, modify, or hide the 'F' button. [[info]](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php)
2. Go to [this page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=178608028874393&ref=hcnav) to navigate the different means of reporting a violation or issue.  The question forum is located under **Get Help and Give Feedback** and is labeled as ***Post and answer questions in the Help Forum***.